# default values for 13 fields mysql

Tags: mysql

So I have the database schema below (3 tables) and the whole purpose of this is to map a nutrient fact table to a package. The Thing is, we want to have at 13 fields in the nutrient fact table that each package should have (even if they're empty), however my current schema only works for entries that contain data.
How can I assign 13  default component name to a package (along with the Unit of Measure and Daily Value)?

```
CREATE TABLE PackageID(
PackageID INT NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE Component(
ComponentID INT NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
Component_Name text
);

CREATE TABLE Product_Component(
PackageID int,
ComponentID int,
Amount varchar(7),
Unit_Of_Measure varchar(7),
Daily_Value varchar(7),
FOREIGN KEY (ComponentID) REFERENCES Component(ComponentID),
FOREIGN KEY (PackageID) REFERENCES Package(PackageID)
);
```

Comment: what nutrient fact table? "product component"? either you insert 13 records into that table for every package, or you just have your client-side code fill in any missing bits when you retrieve a package.

Comment: Use `INSERT` to add the 13 records to your table?

Comment: the way i look at data is that if it ain't good, don't save it

Comment: @MarcB A product component is let say `sodium` which is one of the mandatory fillds in the Nutrient fact table.

Comment: @Jocelyn I have thousands of data so I cant do it manually

Comment: then do the mandatory inserts when you create a product. the db won't do that automatically for you. either client-side code doing inserts, or a stored procedure in the db to do the necessary inserts. but one way or another, you'll HAVE to do 13 inserts to get those child records.